# How do I convert the following in tensorflow version 2

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
print(tensorflow.__version__)
w = tf.Variable(0, dtype = tf.float32)
cost = w**2 - 8*w + 16
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(cost)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
session = tf.Session()
session.run(init)
for i in range(1000):
    session.run(train)

print(session.run(w))
#3.994
```

I googled the stuff but I didn't get any conclusion
this program calculates the factors of the polynomial when I use tf-vr-2 it gives me an error missing var_list i fixed that too but later on it gives more error

Comment: Please share the full error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several changes from TF1 to TF2:

- Optimizers are now in the `keras` module, but there is an alias `tf.optimizers` that can be used. `GradientDescentOptimizer` can be replaced by `SGD` without momentum
- Session object are not used anymore. Instead, the default is eager execution, colser to how one would write standard python code.
- The `@tf.function` decorator can be used to trace the function into a graph, resulting in improved performances. This is not mandatory.
- Global states are less common in TF2, there is no need for `init` ops.

The [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate?hl=en) can be helpful.

```
import tensorflow as tf   

w = tf.Variable(0, dtype = tf.float32)

@tf.function
def cost():
    return w**2 - 8*w + 16
    
train = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01)
for i in range(1000):
    train.minimize(loss=cost, var_list=[w])

print(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

w = tf.Variable(0, dtype = tf.float32)

@tf.function
def cost():
    return w**2 - 8*w + 16


train = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
for i in range(1000):
    train.minimize(loss=cost, var_list=[w])

tf.print(w)
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but it still uses the modules defined in TensorFlow 1